# Excel VBA to activate selectitem in web and go web for data

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, onchange

I'm very fresh to excel VBA. I tried use all potential solutions in the internet for activate selectitem in web and get data table but it didn't work. My Excel VBA code and Javascript is below.

```
Sub GetQuarterFinancials()

Dim ie As Object, URL As String

    URL = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials"
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With ie
 .Visible = True
 .navigate URL

 Do While .Busy
   DoEvents
 Loop
 Do While .readyState <> 4
   DoEvents
 Loop

  Set ticker = ie.document.getElementById("autocomplete_input")
  ticker.value = "FB"

  .document.getElementById("investing_ac_button").Click
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

  Set selectitem = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
  For Each i In selectitem
           i.value = "/investing/stock/msci/financials/income/quarter"
           i.FireEvent ("onchange")
      Next i
 End With
End Sub





    <select style="float:right" onchange="window.location = this.options[selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="/investing/stock/msci/financials" selected="selected">Annual Financials</option>
        <option value="/investing/stock/msci/financials/income/quarter" >Quarter Financials</option>
    </select>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
    <div class="block">
        <h2>Annual Financials for MSCI Inc.</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [css attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target the appropriate option from dropdown then select it.

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls

Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#autocomplete_input").Value = "FB" 'you could avoid search by adding ticker into url
            .querySelector("#investing_ac_button").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim ele As Object
        With .document
            Do
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set ele = .querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/fb/financials/income/quarter']")
            On Error Resume Next
            Loop While ele Is Nothing
            .querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/fb/financials/income/quarter']").Selected = True
            .querySelector(".financials select").FireEvent "onchange"
                Stop 'delete me later
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Adding ticker into url` is surely the best way to go.

Comment: “Quarter financials” is selected in web but no refresh in the page. How can I code it as quarterly data. Thanks

Comment: You may need to turn fireevent onchange on the select element

Comment: Second question. How can I code “quarter financials” following ticker? Ticker is variant. Thanks

Comment: I added .querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/fb/financials/income/quarter']").fireevent ("onchange") but does't work. Did I code correctly?

Comment: Please see update. The event should be on the select element as per my earlier comment. :-)

Comment: Thanks QHarr very much. It works and I appreciate your guides.