# How VBA to code fireevent "on change" in selected terms in Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, onchange

How to code in VBA for fireevent "onchange" in selected term in Javascript. It doesn't work as coding `.querySelector(".zcq0.djhtm?b=Q&a= & var & ").FireEvent "onchange"`. Can someone help it, thanks in advance?

```vb
Public Sub GetTWYIn()
    Dim ie As Object, URL As String, var As Object, ele As Object, td As Date
    Const max_wait_sec As Long = 10

    Set var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1)
    URL = "http://pscnetinvest.moneydj.com.tw/z/zc/zcq/zcqa/zcqa_" & var & ".djhtm"
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            b = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .querySelector("[value$='/zcq0.djhtm?b=Q&a=" & var & "']")

                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - td > max_wait_sec Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing
            If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            ele.Selected = True
            .querySelector(".zcq0.djhtm?b=Q&a= & var & ").FireEvent "onchange"
        End With
    End With
     Set ie = Nothing`
End Sub
```

This is html.

```html
<SELECT name="selB" id="selB" onchange="javascript:selopn(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

<OPTION value="/z/zc/zcq/zcq0.djhtm?b=Q&a=1232" >季表</OPTION>
<OPTION value="/z/zc/zcq/zcq0.djhtm?b=A&a=1232" >累計季表</OPTION>
<OPTION value="/z/zc/zcq/zcq0.djhtm?b=Y&a=1232"  selected>年表</OPTION>

</SELECT>
```

Comment: Can you provide a value for _var_ that produces a valid url for testing please? Also, I think the url is likely location based in terms of access given my experience with the domain. And are you getting any error messages? If so, what?

Comment: Var can be "2330", "1232" and "2317". Please try it. It pops up error method 'queryselector' of object 'Jscripttypeinfo' failed.

Comment: You are going to have to switch to non querySelector e.g. getElementsByTagName and do a loop testing inner text or .valu

Comment: Thanks QHarr your tips. It works with getElementsByTagName(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254532/excel-vba-to-activate-selectitem-in-web-and-go-web-for-data

Comment: you are most welcome.

Comment: I have an issue for web table. Wondering if you have some tips or codes. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533678/how-vba-to-scrape-table-from-web